# Can't get the UploadURL from Microsoft Graph in Upload Session

Tags: python-3.x, file-upload, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have been trying to implement the following procedure with python

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online#create-an-upload-session

I have been trying to get the upload URL part

Please note that I already got the access token and created the required client Id and secret

```
    def getUploadUrl(filename="test.txt"):
        global token
        if (not token):
            with open('token.json', 'r') as f:
                token = json.load(f)
        if (token["expires_at"] < time.time()):
            refreshToken()
        location = "/me/drive/root:/FolderA/" + filename + ":/createUploadSession"
        client = OAuth2Session(client_id=client_id,
                               redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI, token=token)

        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

        json_file = {
            "item": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.driveItemUploadableProperties",
                "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "replace",
                "name": filename
            }
        }
        json_string = json.dumps(json_file, indent=4)
        r = client.post(BaseUrl + location,
                        data=json_string, headers=headers)
        print(r.status_code)
        print(r.text)
        upload_url = ""
        if(r.status_code == 200):
            upload_url = r.json()['uploadUrl']
            return upload_url, r
        else:
            return "", ""
```

I keep getting the following Error response though

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": "invalidRequest",
   "message": "Invalid request",
    "innerError": {
     "request-id": "7893d0aa-fcdb-46bc-b0b6-58fd90c4cb46",
      "date": "2020-03-21T17:15:13"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing till now is just removing 
`@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.driveItemUploadableProperties` from the JSON payload.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload later, maybe it was the service bug.